# How to display an image list in a GridView with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I just started to learn Flutter and I'm not able to find my error...

I'm trying to display images from a list in a Grid View but I can't find why the console can't find the getter 'room'.

I created a class  with a method and a constructor and another data class where are stored the different lists. One of this list depends of the Room class. for now, the other is fixed.

When i call `room.room` the class room is find but the getter .room not.

Do I miss something?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ipictory/datas/datarooms.dart';
import 'package:ipictory/widgets/room.dart';
import 'detail_room.dart';

class DetailRoomTest extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  DetailRoomTestState createState() => DetailRoomTestState();

}

class DetailRoomTestState extends State<DetailRoomTest>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final room = DataRooms().listeDataRooms;
   final roomImages = DataRooms().imageLiving;

    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double width = size.width;
    double heigth = size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(room.room,         //-------> error: The getter 'room' isn't defined 
                                                for the type 'List<Room>'.
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: roomImages.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    child:Image(
                        image: AssetImage(roomImages[index],)
                    ),
                );
              }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:ipictory/widgets/room.dart';

class DataRooms {

  List<Room> listeDataRooms = [

    Room(room: "La salle à manger", inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "Inventaire de la salle à manger : 1 table extensible, 4 chaises en simili cuir et 4 chaises en bois rangées dans le placard.", imagePath: "images/control_images/sallemanger.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages", damages: "impact sur le plateau de la table, chaises en simili griffées à plusieurs endroits", desc: "La salle à manger est composée d'une table en bois extensibles pouvant accueillir 8 personnes." ),
    Room(room: "Salon", inventoryTitle : "Inventaire",inventory: "Inventaire du salon : 1 table basse, 6 coussins bleus en velour, 5 coussins d'assise du canapé, un panier", imagePath: "images/control_images/salon.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "Aucun dommage", desc: "Le salon est composé d'un canapé d'angle en tissu convertible en un lit 2 places et d'une table basse. Une jolie décoration en fait une zone très agréable. La télévision par satelite permet d'occuper les journées de pluie ou les moments de repos. "),
    Room(room: "La cuisine", inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "Inventaire de la cuisine : 2 casseroles, 3 poeles, une vaisselle pour 8 personnes, 2 couteaux de cuisine, etc...", imagePath: "images/control_images/cuisine.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "il manque une cuillère", desc: "La cuisine est entièrement équipée. Cafetière à dosette ou à filtre, théière, grille pain, bouilloire, four à gaz, micro onde, refrigérateur, et plaques au gaz. Tout ce qu'il faut pour faire de bons plats. " ),
    Room(room: "La salle d'eau",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "La salle d'eau contient : 1 petit panier, un sèche cheveux", imagePath: "images/control_images/salle_deau.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "aucun dommage", desc: "Salle de douche parfaite"),
    Room(room: "La chambre parentale",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "la chambre parentale contient : un lit 140, 2 tables de chevets, 2 oreillers et une couverture 240x240", imagePath: "images/control_images/chambreparentale.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "Tache de sang sur le matelas", desc: "super chambre parentale"),
    Room(room: "Le dressing",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "le dressing contient une machine à laver le linge, 2 oreillers supplémentaires, ", imagePath: "images/control_images/dressing.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "aucun dommage", desc: "C'est le dressing de la chambre parentale. Pratique pour tout ranger"),
    Room(room: "chambre 1",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "la chambre 1 contient 2 lit 70cm, 2 oreillers et deux couvertures", imagePath: "images/control_images/chambre1.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "aucun dommage", desc: "super chambre pour enfants. C'est la chambre de Luna et Lana"),
    Room(room: "toilettes",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "Les toilettes contiennent une brosse WC", imagePath: "images/control_images/toilettes.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages", damages: "Aucun dommage" ),
    Room(room: "Terrasse",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "La terrasse contient : 1 table de jardin, 8 chaises de jardin grises, une plancha, un parasol et son pied, un étendoir à linge, etc.", imagePath: "images/control_images/terrasse.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "7 chaises sont cassées" ),
    Room(room: "jardin",inventoryTitle : "Inventaire", inventory: "Le jardin dispose de deux transats ", imagePath: "images/control_images/jardin.png" , damagesTitle : "Dommages",damages: "aucun dommage" ),
  ];

  List imageLiving = [
    "images/lieux/living_room/salon.png",
    "images/lieux/living_room/salon.png",
  ];
}
```

```
class Room {
  String room;

  String inventory;

  String? desc;

  String imagePath;

  String damages;

  String inventoryTitle;

  String damagesTitle;


  Room({
    required this.inventoryTitle,
    required this.room,
    required this.inventory,
    this.desc,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.damages,
    required this.damagesTitle,});

  String getImage() => imagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error basically mean that your room variable is `List<Room>` and `Room`. So, as it's `List<Room>` you cannot access Like this `room.room` you need to access particular index and then access `.room` again like below

EX:

```
final room = DataRooms().listeDataRooms; //List of Room
Text(
  room.first.room // Access the first item from list
  // room[0].room Accesing with the help of index, you can write any number in bracket.
  // room.last.room Accessing last item from list
)
```

Comment: the text displayed must depend on the room. With this code, the title will always be the same regardless of the room

Answer (score 0):

You have defined room as `final room = DataRooms().listeDataRooms;` which itself is a `List<Room>`. (List of Room)

So you can access it by `room[0].room` or `room.first.room`

Comment: the text displayed must depend on the room. With this code, the title will always be the same regardless of the room

Comment: @Haox I have guided with the code how one can use the `List` to access and not for the `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

You need the widget parameter for the room name.

```html
class DetailRoomTest extends StatefulWidget{
  String room;
  const DetailRoomTest({
    Key? key,
    required this.room,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  DetailRoomTestState createState() => DetailRoomTestState();

}

class DetailRoomTestState extends State<DetailRoomTest>{
   late List<String> _roomImages;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    _roomImages = DataRooms().imageLiving;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double width = size.width;
    double heigth = size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.room,       
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: _roomImages.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    child:Image(
                        image: AssetImage(_roomImages[index],)
                    ),
                );
              }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```